# Как умножить на число в списке?

Tags: python, python-3.x

как записать, чтобы 'print(a / b * l)' вывел целое число, а не список 'l' умноженный на 'a/b'

```
elif a * c > d and a != b:
if a / b in l:
    print(a / b * l)
```

Comment: ?????????????????

Comment: Что нужно??? Пример ввода и вывода

Comment: @Victor VosMottor thanks Monica если a / b == 4, то мне надо a / b в нашем случае 4 умножить на 4 в списке l

Comment: @Victor VosMottor thanks Monica чтобы print вывел 16

Comment: Не понял, если честно, примеры дайте ;)

Comment: А чтоб принт вывел 16 : `print(16)` ;)

Comment: [Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: `print(*map(lambda elem: elem*2, filter(lambda el:not (el%4), your_list))` ?

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica, есть решение попроще: `print((a / b) ** 2)` ;)

Comment: Я обновил вопрос

Comment: Не, ну я пытался понять "че надо?".  i did my best ;)

Comment: Так стало еще менее понятно. Можете _словами_ что есть, что надо, и каким образом.

Answer (score 3):

Вот так вот:

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
a, b = 8, 2 

if a / b in l:
  l[l.index(a / b)] *= 4

print(l)
```

Comment: Не надо отвечать на непонятный вопрос ;)